# what is the reason for returning a function while decorating in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I wanna decorate a function with python and I don't know why should i return the outer function at the end of the code?

```
def outer_function():
   word = "hi"
   def inner_function():
       print(word)
   return inner_function
outer_function()
```

Comment: Then why do you want to even decorate a function? What do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: I've put your code into code formatting, please fix the indentation. Currently you only return the inner function

Comment: There are no decorators in your code. And there are multiple syntax errors.

Comment: What you have coded is not a function decorator. SO is not meant to be a primer on the Python language.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind decorators is, to *decorate* a function. This means, that you have a function and want to extend or slightly modify it's behavior without changing the function itself. As SO is not the place for an introduction into Python in general and decorators in specific, here's a simple example of a decorator and a link to a very good RealPython article explaining them in more depth.

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")
```

Link: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

A hope this helps you. Have a nice day!